# How do I change the subscription server endpoint in Apollo express server?

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

When creating an Apollo Server with express the http and subscriptions endpoints default to /graphql. When changing the http endpoint to something other than /graphql the subscription endpoint stays pointed at /graphql. How do I make my subscription endpoint the same as my http endpoint?

Here is the example from Apollo website where I only add `path: custom_endpoint`

````
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');

const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.applyMiddleware({app, path: custom_endpoint})

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);

// ⚠️ Pay attention to the fact that we are calling `listen` on the http server variable, and not on `app`.
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`) //this changes to my custom_endpoint
  console.log(` Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:${PORT}${server.subscriptionsPath}`) // this does not chnage to my custome_endpoint.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ApolloServer` constructor accepts a `subscriptions` parameter that can be used to customize the subscription endpoint as [shown in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#constructoroptions-apolloserver).

> **`subscriptions`: `<Object> | <String> | false`**
>
> String defining the path for subscriptions or an Object to customize the subscriptions server. Set to false to disable subscriptions
>
> - `path`: `<String>`
> - `keepAlive`: `<Number>`
> - `onConnect`: `<Function>`
> - `onDisconnect`: `<Function>`

Answer (score -1):

initialize the ApolloServer instance as follows:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  subscriptions: { path: '/custom-graphql-ws' }
});
```